# SendMessage user32dll on an internet explorer page

Tags: c#

I have an Internet Explorer page opend on my desktop. The name of the webpage is TEST. With FindWindow() from user32.dll i can get a handler over the window. In this page I have a button called Go and I 2 textboxes called Name and Surname. How can I write in thewebpage my name and surname and than click Go programatically? THX

Answer (score 2):

The normal approach to updating foreign windows (`WM_SETTEXT` et al) won't work because the form components within IE are not stock windows, rather they are rendered by IE itself.

To manipulate them you need to call via the DOM (or use something like [WaitN](http://watin.org/)).

```
using mshtml;  //.net ref microsoft.mshtml
using SHDocVw; //com ref `microsoft internet controls` + change ref to no embed interop 

int HWND = 0x001C0C10; //your IE 
foreach(InternetExplorer ie in new ShellWindowsClass()) {
   //find the instance
   if (ie.HWND == HWND) {
      //get doc
      HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument)ie.Document;
       doc.getElementsByName("name").item(0).value = "bob";
       doc.getElementsByName("surname").item(0).value = "smith";
       doc.getElementsByName("go").item(0).click();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your asking is actually possible with Using Win32 (user32.dll), having said that
If your trying to interact with the web server then you could simply use httprequest and httpresponse class to GET and POST variables as required.

```
HttpWebRequest testRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://.....");
HttpWebResponse testResponse = (HttpWebResponse)testRequest.GetResponse();
string responseStatus = testResponse.StatusCode.ToString();
testResponse.Close();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.aspx
```

If your tring to test or reply a standard set of event then you may want to have a look at Fiddler

```
http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/
```