# WM_SETTEXT doesn't work for Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, automation, postmessage

I need to send message to internet explorer window, i want to log in onto my gmail account. The problem is that ie doesn't react at WM_SETTEXT event.

Here's a snippet

```
IntPtr hWndIe = NativeMethods.FindWindow("IEFrame", null);
IntPtr hWndtab = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hWndIe, IntPtr.Zero, "Frame Tab", null);
IntPtr hWndtabw = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hWndtab, IntPtr.Zero, "TabWindowClass", null);
IntPtr hWndshell = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hWndtabw, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", null);
IntPtr hWndEdit = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hWndshell, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", null);

NativeMethods.PostMessage(hWndEdit, WM_KEYDOWN, Keys.Tab, IntPtr.Zero);
NativeMethods.SendMessage(hWndEdit, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "xxx@gmail.com");
```

At the same time

```
NativeMethods.PostMessage(hWndEdit, WM_KEYDOWN, Keys.B, IntPtr.Zero);
```

works fine.

Any help would be appreciated.

UPD: Here's [SendMessage user32dll on an internet explorer page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964384/sendmessage-user32dll-on-an-internet-explorer-page) a similar question. And the solution is to find another approach.