# How Do I Click Web Button In VBA

Tags: vba

I've spent hours reading through Stack Overflow, but can't find an answer which works for me.  I'm using VBA, and using Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library.

Here's my code (which allows me to enter user name and password information even if there is no "value" or "id" information ... only "name" information):

```
' Incorporating Microsoft Internet Controls AND Microsoft HTML Object Library
' Webpage loaded constant
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
' Declare Windows API function for setting active window
Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetForegroundWindow" (ByVal Hwnd As Long)As Long
' Declare Internet Explorer object
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Sub Main
SetMicrophone 0
   ' create instance of InternetExplorer
   Set IE = New InternetExplorer
   ' using your newly created instance of Internet Explorer
   With IE
      SetForegroundWindow IE.HWND
      .Visible = True
      .Navigate2 "http://www.NakedCapitalism.com/wp-admin"
     ' Wait until page we are navigating to is loaded
      Do While .Busy
      Loop
      Do
      Loop Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      ' the username and password values will not exist if already logged in
      ' so no need to fill in the values and go straight to Next
      On Error Resume Next
         If Err Then
           'Do Nothing
         Else
          ' When the page is fully loaded enter your username and password
          ' you will need to set these appropriately
  End If
     Dim inputs As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim iFrames As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim iFrame As MSHTML.HTMLFrameElement
    ' Get top_window frame and navigate to it then
    Set doc = IE.document
    Set iFrames = doc.getElementsByName("top_window")
    If Not iFrames Is Nothing Then
        Set iFrame = iFrames(0)
        IE.navigate url & iFrame.src
              Set inputs = doc.getElementsByName("log")
        If Not inputs Is Nothing Then
            inputs(0).value = "MyUserName"
        End If
    End If
    Set IE = Nothing
   End With
    ' Get top_window frame and navigate to it then
    Set doc = IE.document
    Set iFrames = doc.getElementsByName("top_window")
    If Not iFrames Is Nothing Then
        Set iFrame = iFrames(0)
        IE.navigate url & iFrame.src
        Set inputs = doc.getElementsByName("pwd")
        If Not inputs Is Nothing Then
            inputs(0).value = "MyPassword"
        End If
    End If
    Set IE = Nothing
   ' Tidy Up
   SetMicrophone 1
End Sub
```

I'm trying to click the button which has the following code:

```
<p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Log In" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://www.nakedcapitalism.com/wp-admin/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    </p>
```

Help!?

Comment: have you checked here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5964384/sendmessage-user32dll-on-an-internet-explorer-page

Comment: Looks like that's c# instead of VBA ... or am I reading it incorrectly?

Comment: I think they are using the same object reference. Based on their code something like doc.getElementsByName("wp-submit").item(0).click() might work for you. See also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Caleb! That worked!  How do I indicate that you successfully answered the question?

Comment: Glad to hear it! you can accept my answer that I resubmitted below :-)

Comment: Caleb, I'm a newbie, and don't see an "accept" button to accept your answer.  How do I accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work for you (VBA code should be similar):

```
doc.getElementsByName("wp-submit").item(0).click()
```

For button "click" method see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279(v=vs.85).aspx

For form "submit" method see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752432(v=vs.85).aspx

These 2 links may help you as well, showing how to reference the IE document and elements with SHDocVW (which is what it looks like you are using):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084(v=vs.85).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
Sub ClickMe()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim myZip As Long
Dim siteZip As Object
Dim URL As String
Dim gender As Object
Dim btnGo As Object

Sub Macro_1()
myZip = "12345"
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
URL = "Individual and Family Health Insurance"
IE.navigate (URL)

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4

Set siteZip = IE.document.getElementById("census_zipCode")
siteZip.Value = myZip

Set gender = IE.document.getElementById("census_primary_gender")
gender.Value = "MALE"

Set btnGo = IE.document.forms(0).all("method:submit") ' method:submit is the button's name
btnGo.Click

End Sub
```